# how do i add customizer edit option without plugin in wp

Tags: codex

when i go to wp customizer then i want edit the name **popular** and 
cat_id =**21**

---

```
<div class="p_list"><h2><span>popular</span></h2>   
    <?php $first = true; ?> <?php $cat_id = 21;
$latest_cat_post = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 4, 'category__in' => array($cat_id)));
if( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : while( $latest_cat_post->have_posts() ) : $latest_cat_post->the_post();  ?>
```

Comment: Note that you can do something a plugin does without a plugin, by copy pasting it into a theme and deleting the comment at the top, then including it from `functions.php`. Your site won't be any faster though, you'll have just made it more complicated. Otherwise I'm not sure I understand your question, can you reword it? Also can you reformat your code? It's very difficult to read, and has no indentation, all the PHP is on a single line

Answer (score -1):

The customizer, as it is mostly for style settings.

If you want to make a heading dynamic then you could create a custom field. Then echo that into the page or post template using the get_post_meta function, and wrap it in whatever HTML tags you wish.

Hope this helps!

check these out:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/

https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/#displaying-custom-fields

Or you could try these plugins:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: i need just change the cat number and popular text . without plugin